# How to get the 1.7.0_45 JDK on Yosemite?

Tags: java

(Apologies if this is better suited for SuperUser.)

I want to have this Java on my machine:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I found [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html), but it doesn't actually offer a download link. I found [the page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) for downloading **1.7.0_75**, but that is not what I need.

Is there a place I can just download **1.7.0_45** directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will probably be marked off-topic, but you can access the Java download archives through the Oracle Java SE site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html

Answer (score 3):

Here a good hint to find files on the internet you would not easily find or normally need an account to download :

Google -> Search for

```
"index-of" jdk 1.7.0
```

You'll find out that many website's index are not secure at all and since many of them probably host a `jdk` jar you should be able to find your file easily that way. Note that I know it might be easier in the case of `jdk` to simply go on the `Oracle` archive, but I tought I'd like to give an interesting answer to a non-interesting question as this tip is useful to find files rapidly on internet.

**Edit :** this might not be legal so... don't do it...

Comment: @Rosarch You should have a look at my answer, if it does not help you than at least it will help you a lot in the future when searching hidden files.

Comment: haha yes I will check it out. I don't know what wouldn't be legal about it - if someone is exposing more to the open internet than they want then it's their problem.

Comment: @Rosarch I agree, just trying to protect myself :P